# Mpdf error - Number of horizontal metrics is 0

Tags: php, symfony, mpdf

I am not sure what is causing this error:

```
Number of horizontal metrics is 0
```

My code is like this:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
        'mode'                => 'utf-8',
        'format'              => 'A4',
        'orientation'         => 'L',
        'tempDir'             => '/tmp/',
        'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'pad',
    ]);

$mpdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait
        '', '', '', '',
        15, // margin_left
        15, // margin right
        15, // margin top
        20, // margin bottom
        0, // margin header
        10); // margin footer
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);

    ob_end_clean();

    return $mpdf->Output();
```

I guess this is an font related error because every time i activate and deactivate `$mpdf->debugfonts = true;` it seems to be working...

Comment: Are you trying to use a custom font? What is your environment, PHP version etc? BTW, the AddPage call is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `mode` to `c` (instead of `utf-8`) in the constructor.

```
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'mode'=>'c',
  'orientation'=>'P',
  'format'=>'Letter',
  // 'allow_output_buffering' => true,
  // 'debugfonts' => true,
  'fontDir'=>array_merge($fontDirs, [
    __DIR__.'/../../fonts/roboto',
  ]),
  'fontdata'=>$fontData+[
      'roboto'=>[
        'R'=>'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        'I'=>'Roboto-Italic.ttf',
      ]
    ],
  'default_font_size'=>9,
  'default_font'=>'DejaVuSans'
]);
```